# Fluently map Id

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I have got the following problem when i tried to map my classes

```
 Stack trace:
 Inner exception message: could not resolve property: Project_ID of: Messenia.Data.Models.Project
```

here is my config

```
  private StaticHibernate () {
            new NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory ();
            SessionFactory = Fluently.Configure ()
                 .Database (MySQLConfiguration.Standard
                 .ConnectionString ("database=messenia;server=localhost;uid=root;pwd=root"))
                 .ExposeConfiguration (c => c.Properties.Add ("hbm2ddl.keywords", "none"))
                 .Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings.Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Entity>(new EntityAutoMappingConfiguration())

                                                                        .IgnoreBase<Entity>()
                                                                        .UseOverridesFromAssemblyOf<Entity>()
                                                                        .Conventions.Add(typeof(PrimaryKeyNamePlusId))))                                                                        .BuildSessionFactory ();
```

and :

```
 public class EntityAutoMappingConfiguration : DefaultAutomappingConfiguration
    {
        public override bool ShouldMap(Type type)
        {
            return type.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IPersistable));
        }


    }
```

and :

```
public class PrimaryKeyNamePlusId : IIdConvention
    {
        public void Apply(IIdentityInstance instance)
        {
            instance.Column(instance.EntityType.Name + "_ID");
        }
    }
```

class project doesn't contains property Project_Id but it contains prop Id so why i get this error ? thanks .
can somebody help me to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess, because I've always found FNH's default Id handling to be perfectly satisfactory, but...

I think your PrimaryKeyNamePlusId class is telling FNH to expect all of the ID properties in your entities to be in the form _ID, but you say your Project entity's ID property is just called "Id", so FNH can't find it.

You could test this by changing the property name in Project e.g.

```
    public virtual Guid Project_ID { get;  protected set; }
```

and see if the error goes away.